# Test or drill to verify the functioning of a judicial system by ordinary people

Tags: judiciary

Is there any mechanism in any judicial system to test its efficiency by designing a fake or test crime scheme to verify the functionality of the judiciary?  For example, is there a method for a student to detect what problems exist in the administrative system and conduct codes of their University?

Comment: This might be a question for Law.SE, it seems more legal than political.

Comment: [The Innocence Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innocence_Project) cites various studies estimating that in the United States, between 2.3% and 5% of all prisoners are innocent (based on DNA testing). If you want to know what this is, then look up the accuracy of eye witness testimony.

Comment: Courts often routinely refuse to hear appears when new evidence is brought up, so the answer is No. The Judicial system is not very concerned with accuracy as much as with maintaining public order.

Comment: In the US and the UK (and I suspect, in most systems derived from those) creating a 'fake crime' is itself a crime (filing a false report, wasting police business, lying to Federal officers, contempt of court...). And as a general moral rule, tricking people to expose dishonesty destroys your own credibility as much (if not more) than theirs. The academic approach relies on careful, neutral examination, not deceit.

Comment: @TedWrigley, Saying something doesn't exist in nation X, doesn't prove there's no nation Z where it does exist.  The general moral rule would be inapplicable here, since the clear intent would be to improve the system rather than harm it, similar to the theory and practice condoning undercover police.

Comment: @agc: The idea that police *anywhere* will take kindly to having a citizen 'investigating' them, because they recognize the citizen has high-minded intentions, is naïve to the point of ludicrousness. Police will invariably see such as a threat to their authority and an inversion of social roles, and will address it harshly. I remember a case in the US where someone took a video of police behaving badly, sent it out over social media, and less than a week later had swat officers burst into his home on a no-knock warrant, for no real reason. Pure intimidation...

Comment: @TedWrigley, Clarification:  by *"...condoning undercover police"* I'd intended to signify people like [Joseph D. Pistone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_D._Pistone), or the protagonists of [*The Meeting Place Cannot Be Changed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Meeting_Place_Cannot_Be_Changed), *etc.*.  Which is to say, that even within law enforcement itself there is a  body of theory and practice which condones diagnostic role playing, as distinct from role playing as criminal fraud, or as entertainment. .